# Test for statistical distribution

Tags: r, distributions, distribution-identification

I'm new to statistical analysis and I'm trying to identify which distribution fits my BD better. My BD has length of stay (LOS) data in two different hospitals: `HOSP_A` and `HOSP_B`.

My BD:

```
LOS<- c('< 2','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','> 30')
HOSP_A <- c(39952,21720,11131,7451,5369,3981,3695,2543,1938,1607,1202,982,905,888,730,536,560,496,408,372,357,303,269,244,167,174,165,177,153,105,1668)  
HOSP_B <- c(13869,6673,3995,2543,2032,1749,1465,1207,977,835,745,608,557,535,461,331,362,273,224,265,245,200,160,160,150,127,120,118,95,82,1529)
DF<- data.frame(LOS,HOSP_A,HOSP_B)
```

I tried to use the code below, but I was in doubt if the length of stay fits the BETA distribution

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(logspline)
descdist(DF$HOSP_A, discrete = FALSE)
```

Is there a test to identify the best distribution? Furthermore, do HOSP_A and HOSP_B follow the same distribution?

Comment: Hospital length of stay often follows a log normal distribution, but your data is discretised, making this harder to check. It's not clear how it could follow a beta distribution which is continuous, and bounded between 0 and 1, or am I misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: I probably didn't know how to express it correctly, and I also interpreted the data incorrectly in relation to the BETA distribution.
I grouped the length of stay in these intervals, which makes the distribution non-continuous. Is there any way to calculate the distribution with the data being discrete?

Comment: Do you still have the raw length of stay data?

Comment: @BrunoAvila you need to pick a suitable distribution based on properties of the underlying phenomenon. Is your variable bounded from above? from below? What about tails? Is the distribution symmetric or not? These are the questions you should be asking yourself.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: What does BD stand for? Please be explicit.